# Minimax algorithm for tic tac toe in Python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, tic-tac-toe, ai

I am using minimax algorithm (for now without alpha beta pruning) for AI in tic tac toe game in Python and Numpy. It's working, but very slow, so I would like to optimize it.

A few rules for current purposes:

- Board is 4x4 square,
- Player wins when he has 3 symbols (X or O) in row, column or diagonal,
- Empty field is represented by `0`, X by `1` and O by `2`.
- There is no whole game for performance testing. Goal is to determine only one next move (player 1 must play `(2, 1)`) using minimax like bellow:

```
[[1 0 0 1]         [[1 0 0 1]
 [0 2 0 0]    ->    [0 2 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]          [0 1 1 0]
 [1 2 2 1]]         [1 2 2 1]]
```

[Here](https://repl.it/repls/EnviousElegantLanguage) is whole program. Even game board is almost full, get optimal move takes 3 seconds. Most of the time takes function `search_sequence` and then `minimax`. Is there any way to optimize it? Bellow are described some parts of program.

### search_sequence

Function accepts array and sequence (also array) and check, if array includes sequence.

```
# E. g. [1 2 3 4 5] includes [2 3 4] but not [5 4 3].
def search_sequence(arr, seq):
    r_seq = numpy.arange(seq.shape[0])
    M = (arr[numpy.arange(arr.shape[0] - seq.shape[0] + 1)[:, None] + r_seq] == seq).all(1)
    return M.any() > 0
```

### get_diags

Accepts 2D array and return list of all diagonals.

```
# [[1 2 3]        
#  [4 5 6]  ->  [[1] [2 4] [7 5 3] [8 6] [9] [3] [2 6] [1 5 9] [4 8] [7]]         
#  [7 8 9]]         
def get_diags(state):
    diags = [state[::-1,:].diagonal(i) for i in range(-state.shape[0] + 1, state.shape[1])]
    diags.extend(state.diagonal(i) for i in range(state.shape[1]-1,-state.shape[0],-1))
    return diags
```

### Player.get_actions

Return list of all available actions. Action is simple tuple,

```
# [[1 2 0]
#  [1 2 1]   ->  [(0, 1) (2, 0) (2, 2)]
#  [0 1 0]]
def get_actions(self, state):
    coords = numpy.asarray(numpy.where(state == 0)).T
    return [tuple(i) for i in coords]
```

### Player.apply_action, Player.undo_action

Apply action to game board. Simply set value on action's coordinates to player's ID.

```
def apply_action(self, state, action):
    state[action] = self.id
    return state

def undo_action(self, state, action):
    state[action] = 0
    return state
```

### Player.is_win

Search all rows, columns and diagonals for sequence of 3 player's ID.

```
# [[1 2 0]
#  [1 2 1]   ->  True (for player with id = 2)
#  [0 2 0]]
def is_win(self, state):
    for i, row in enumerate(state):
        if search_sequence(row, self.win_seq):
            return True

        if search_sequence(state[:, i], self.win_seq):
            return True

    for diag in get_diags(state):
        if search_sequence(diag, self.win_seq):
            return True

    return False
```

### Player.is_full

Check if there is no field 0 on game board and no move is available.

```
def is_full(self, state):
    fields = state == 0
    return not fields.any()
```

### Player.minimax

Return score of state tree. 0 = draw, -10 = loss, 10 = win.

```
def minimax(self, state, depth, is_max):
    if self.is_win(state):
        return 10 - depth
    elif self.enemy.is_win(state):
        return -10 + depth
    elif self.is_full(state):
        return 0

    actions = self.get_actions(state)

    if is_max:
        best = -sys.maxsize

        for action in actions:
            val = self.minimax(self.apply_action(state, action), depth + 1, False)
            self.undo_action(state, action)
            best = max(best, val)
    else:
        best = sys.maxsize

        for action in actions:
            val = self.minimax(self.enemy.apply_action(state, action), depth + 1, True)
            self.undo_action(state, action)
            best = min(best, val)

    return best
```

### Player.get_decision

Get optimal action for next move.

```
def get_decision(self, state, enemy):
    self.enemy = enemy
    actions = self.get_actions(state)
    best_i = None
    best_val = -sys.maxsize

    for i, action in enumerate(actions):
        val = self.minimax(self.apply_action(state, action), 0, False)
        state[action] = 0

        if val > best_val:
            best_i = i
            best_val = val

    return actions[best_i]
```

Comment: My IDE is giving me a warning about the `.all(1)` in `search_sequence()`, any idea what's going on? The message is: "Unresolved attribute reference 'all' for class 'bool'".

Answer (score 2):

Initially your code was taking about 19-20 secs to complete.
I added memoization, now it takes 2-3 secs to complete.
Hope it helps.
In case you have to rerun program many times. I have saved the 'mydict' object using 'pickle'. then reuse it. 
In case of reuse, program takes less than 1 second
[Repl link for the code](https://repl.it/repls/ViciousNearComputerscience)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import numpy
import time
import sys
import pickle
start = time.time()
try:
  with open('mydict','rb') as f:
    print('using previous file')
    mydict = pickle.load(f)
except:
  mydict = {}
class Player:

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.win_seq = numpy.array([id, id, id])

    def get_actions(self, state):
        coords = numpy.asarray(numpy.where(state == 0)).T
        return [tuple(i) for i in coords]

    def apply_action(self, state, action):
        state[action] = self.id
        return state

    def undo_action(self, state, action):
        state[action] = 0
        return state

    def is_win(self, state):
        for i, row in enumerate(state):
            if search_sequence(row, self.win_seq):
                return True

            if search_sequence(state[:, i], self.win_seq):
                return True

        for diag in get_diags(state):
            if search_sequence(diag, self.win_seq):
                return True

        return False

    def get_decision(self, state, enemy):
        self.enemy = enemy
        actions = self.get_actions(state)
        best_i = None
        best_val = -sys.maxsize

        for i, action in enumerate(actions):
            val = self.minimax(self.apply_action(state, action), 0, False)
            state[action] = 0

            if val > best_val:
                best_i = i
                best_val = val

        return actions[best_i]

    def minimax(self, state, depth, is_max):
        try:
          return mydict[tuple(state.flatten())]
        except:
          pass
        if self.is_win(state):
            return 10 - depth
        elif self.enemy.is_win(state):
            return -10 + depth
        elif self.is_full(state):
            return 0

        actions = self.get_actions(state)

        if is_max:
            best = -sys.maxsize

            for action in actions:
                val = self.minimax(self.apply_action(state, action), depth + 1, False)
                self.undo_action(state, action)
                best = max(best, val)
        else:
            best = sys.maxsize

            for action in actions:
                val = self.minimax(self.enemy.apply_action(state, action), depth + 1, True)
                self.undo_action(state, action)
                best = min(best, val)

        mydict[tuple(state.flatten())]=best

        return best

    def is_full(self, state):
        fields = state == 0
        return not fields.any()

def search_sequence(arr, seq):
    r_seq = numpy.arange(seq.shape[0])
    M = (arr[numpy.arange(arr.shape[0] - seq.shape[0] + 1)[:, None] + r_seq] == seq).all(1)
    return M.any() > 0

def get_diags(state):
    diags = [state[::-1,:].diagonal(i) for i in range(-state.shape[0] + 1, state.shape[1])]
    diags.extend(state.diagonal(i) for i in range(state.shape[1]-1,-state.shape[0],-1))
    return diags

me = Player(1)
enemy = Player(2)

state = numpy.array([
    [1, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 2, 2, 1]
])

decision = me.get_decision(state, enemy)

print(state)
print(decision)
print(me.apply_action(state, decision))

print(time.time() - start, "s")

with open('mydict','wb') as f:
  pickle.dump(mydict,f)
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview! I like the rewrite, but can you review the OP code some more beyond the fact that it's slow and missing memoization? This is CodeReview after all.

Comment: Thank you sir, you for pointing out. I just did similar to stackoverflow. I am currently reading other answers on codereview. Now I am realizing, That this is not the good way ( in which I have written) to write answers here on codereview.